# Rotina automática de leitura entre 2 bancos de dados em C#

Tags: c#, scheduler

Eu necessito criar uma rotina em C# que faça a leitura de 2 bancos de dados e alimente os dados da leitura em um outro banco. A parte de desenvolvimento do sistema em si eu consigo fazer sem problemas, porém não sei que tipo de projeto desenvolver. Essa rotina será executada semanalmente e ela deve ser publicada/alocada em um server.

Minha dúvida é: "Qual é a forma correta de se desenvolver tal rotina? Seria a criação de um executável que seria acionado pelo [scheduler](/questions/tagged/scheduler) do windows? Ou criar um serviço?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A resposta depende do tipo de hospedagem que sua aplicação pode ter.

Se você vai hospedar em algum lugar que te dá hospedagem `web` compartilhada (*shared web hosting*), você está limitado a ASP.NET. Nesse caso, faria uma aplicação web, com um ponto de chamada (i.e.: um *web service*), e por fora você precisaria de um **cron job** (um serviço que acessa uma página ou web service em horários determinados).

Se você puder lançar um executável ou serviço no servidor (que pode ser sua máquina pessoal, ou uma máquina na empresa), então esses são os prós e contras para cada modelo:

- **Aplicativo:** você pode usar o scheduler, como falou, para chamar seu aplicativo. O scheduler faz o papel de **cron job**. A principal desvantagem é a segurança... Qualque pessoa com acesso e mal intencionada pode substituir seu executável por outra *assembly* maliciosa.
- **Serviço:** você pode escrever a rotina da própria ativação da rotina, e o serviço é o próprio **cron job**. Se o serviço falhar, ele pode se reiniciar automaticamente. É bem mais difícil substituir seu serviço por algo malicioso e as configurações de autenticação/que conta ele vai usar são bem mais fáceis. A única desvantagem importante é que ele é um pouco, mas apenas um pouco, mais complexo do que um aplicativo executável. Ah, e você precisa ser administrador da máquina para colocá-lo para rodar, mas acho que no seu caso isso não deve ser problema.

Eu pessoalmente ficaria com o serviço.